# Multiple conditions on lambda expression to pass using Func

Tags: c#

I have a repository which is like the following. I use `Func` to pass a lambda expression, but I don't know how to do so.

```
public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return table.ToList();
}
```

In my controller I want to pass a condition via lambda like the following, but I don't know how:

```
var rslt = _repository.SelectAll(s=>s.Name="Jack" && s.Time==Date.Now())
```

How should I pass such a lambda, the above lambda is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it to `.Where()`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{

    return table.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put into a extension

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return items.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

example:

```
List<int> items = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5 };
var result = items = items.SelectAll(x => x > 1 && x < 5);
```